# Gulp compiles in my IDE, but breaks site when viewing localhost using nodemon

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gulp, nodemon

I'm fairly new to coding, but have used Gulp a few times successfully, so I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong.  In trying to solve this on my own I've deleted node_modules and re-installed, updated my CDNs to the latest versions, (temporarily) disabled any minification of js and css, and double checked my file paths are cited correctly.  Also, prior to using Gulp all file paths to scripts were hardcoded in index.html and worked fine.

Currently Gulp seems to be compiling in my IDE(atom), but when I use nodemon, and go to localhost, my site is broken. The errors inspector gives me are:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/bundle.css localhost/:23
GET http://localhost:5000/bundle.js angular.js:38
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

[Here's what my file structure looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5M6JG.png)

And here's my code:

```
//index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bundle.css" media="screen" title="no title">
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <ui-view></ui-view>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="./bundle.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>

//gulpfile.js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var annotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate');

var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin');
var htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

var paths = {
    jsSource: ['./public/js/**/*.js'],
    sassSource: ['./public/styles/**/*.scss'],
    indexSource: ['./public/index.html'],
    routesSource: ['./public/routes/**/*.html']
};

gulp.task('sass', function () {
 return gulp.src(paths.sassSource)
   .pipe(sass())
   .pipe(concat('bundle.css'))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});

gulp.task('js', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.jsSource)
        .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
        // .pipe(annotate())
        // .pipe(uglify())
        // .pipe(rename({extname: ".min.js"}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
});

gulp.task('routes', function() {
    gulp.src(paths.routesSource)
      .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/routes'))
})

gulp.task('index', function() {
    gulp.src(paths.indexSource)
      .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
})

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(paths.jsSource, ['js']);
    gulp.watch(paths.sassSource, ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(paths.indexSource, ['index']);
    gulp.watch(paths.routesSource, ['routes']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['js', 'sass', 'watch', 'index'
]);
```

Also, I was asked to give an example of a decloration of a controller and service.

```
//homeCtrl
angular.module('app')
  .controller('homeCtrl', function ($scope, $state, mainService, homeService, user) {

  $scope.user = user;

  $scope.addpo = function (ponum) {
    homeService.addpo(ponum).then(function (response) {
      alert("PO added successfully");
      $state.reload('home');
    })
  };
//homeService
angular.module('app')
.service('homeService', function ($http) {
  this.addpo = function (ponumber) {
    return $http ({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/api/checkin',
      data: {  
        ponumber: ponumber, 
        checkpoint_id: 1 
      }
    }).then(function (response) {
      return response.data;
    });
 };

});
```

Comment: Are you _"injecting"_ controllers and services properly with their dependencies? This might cause this kind of error. The `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]` indicates that a dependency couldn't be resolve. Post an example of the declaration of a controller and a service of yours. That would be useful in order to help you.

Comment: @lealceldeiro  thanks for the quick reply! to clarify, though everything worked correctly prior to using Gulp,  there's a chance that controllers were not injected correctly? If so, I'll totally start working on a fix.

Comment: Yes, that's completely possible. Before minifying files it won't throw any error even when they are not _"injected"_ properly. Only after minification it will throw those errors. That's because how the injection system of AngularJS works. That's way I asked you for a piece of code of a controller/service declaration, for instance `angular.module('app').controller('myCtrl', function(someService){ //...});`

Comment: @lealceldeiro  gotcha!  i added the info you asked for if I understood correctly.

Comment: Please, check out my answer. Hope it helps!